# Coding a function

Tags: r, function, probability

I have an assignment question that I feel would be easier with a function. I tried it and received an error. My question is, how could I code the highlighted math into a function? I want the function to return the probability output when I change the sample size.

In the highlighted math, for example, the sample size is 24 and I have to select 20.

Picture Below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN4HV.png)

I want the function to essentially be like the equation below, and I want to input different sample sizes to produce the output.

> P(X=20) &=& {Sample_Size \choose 20}* (0.90^20)*(0.10^4) = "Output"

Here is what I tried doing to no avail, with the error

> unexpected symbol in "Probability<-function ..."

```
Probability <- function(Sample_Size) {Probability<- choose(Sample_Size,X)*.9^X *.10^(Sample_Size-X) return(Probability)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include code as cut-and-pasted text (with code formatting using triple-backquotes or indentation), rather than a screenshot

Comment: @RuiBarradas, please **don't** edit  (or at least consider not editing) questions to inline images from users who aren't allowed to include images (I did this until recently when I decided it was bad/against SO consensus because it doesn't do as much to educate new users ...) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341336/rollback-edit-which-inlined-very-low-quality-image

Comment: @BenBolker OK, I could have reverted the edit but you already did it. I'll read the meta, of which I didn't know.

Comment: in your last example, you're missing a new line (or semicolon) before `return` ...

Comment: hi! this code might work with @Ben Bolker 's tip but keep in mind that the "X" in your function is not defined within the function which might lead to problems. either pass it as a variable (similar to sample_size) or define it within the function

Comment: Apologies, as I mentioned I'm very new to all this and just created my account on here minutes before I posted the question.

Comment: don't be sorry. all good. we all started exactly like this.

Comment: `Probability <- function(x, size)choose(size, x) * 0.9^x * 0.10^(size - x)`. And `Probability(20, 24)` gives the result in the image, `0.1291874`. You can also compute `sum(Probability(x=20:24, 24))` to give `0.9149251`.

Comment: It is already one of the standard R functions. dbinom(n, N, p) gives you the probability of selecting n from a total of N given the probability of each selection is p.
So, dbinom(20, 24, 0.9) = 0.1291874.

Comment: BTW, if you want your LaTeX to render properly you need curly-bracket the exponents, e.g. `0.90^{20}`

Answer (score 1):

There is already a function in R that will do this for you.  It is called `dbinom` (since it looks like you are working with the binomial distribution).

Here is an example of how to use it:

```r
dbinom(x = 20, size = 24, prob = 0.9)
#> [1] 0.1291874
dbinom(x = 21, size = 24, prob = 0.9)
#> [1] 0.221464
dbinom(x = 22, size = 24, prob = 0.9)
#> [1] 0.2717968
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

- The first parameter (x) takes the number of success you want to get the probability of.
- The second (size) takes the sample size
- And the third (prob) takes the probability of a success.

Answer (score 0):

it should look like this:

```
your_input # sample_size

Probability<-function(Sample_Size, X) {
   Probability<- choose(Sample_Size,X)*.9^X *.10^(Sample_Size-X) 
   return(Probability)
 }
    
Probability(your_input, 20) # 20 being a random input number -> depends on your X value
```

see @Rui Barradas 's answer